# Storing hour&minute values from TimePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm writing an App that get the hour/minute value from TimePicker, display them on the screen and set these values in AlarmManager to ring the alarm.

I can display the hour and minute on screen correctly, but I can't store them for using alarmManager. How can I do that?

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

static final int timePicker1 = 1;

//need to store values in here
static int aHour1, aMin1;

private int mChosenTime = 1;

int cur = 0;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mChosenTime = bundle.getInt("TIME", 1);
    }

    switch (mChosenTime) {
        case timePicker1:
            cur = timePicker1;
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (cur == timePicker1) {
        TextView alarmTimePicker01 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker01);
        alarmTimePicker01.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
        aHour1 = valueOf(hourOfDay);
        aMin1 = valueOf(minute);
}
```

(* I think my code is some kind of... 'strange'. Sorry about that :( )

Comment: where you are getting error

Comment: aHour1 = valueOf(hourOfDay);
aMin1 = valueOf(minute); , aHour1 and aMin1 got nothing...

Comment: paste your logcat with error in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
        new Intent(context, MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: God, Thank you! I thought it was timepickers problem but I had typo on alarmManager part...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code .I implement in my application by below code...

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        String AM_PM = " AM";
                        String mm_precede = "";
                        if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                            AM_PM = " PM";
                            if (hourOfDay >= 13 && hourOfDay < 24) {
                                hourOfDay -= 12;
                            } else {
                                hourOfDay = 12;
                            }
                        } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                            hourOfDay = 12;
                        }
                        if (minute < 10) {
                            mm_precede = "0";
                        }

                        editTeimet.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + mm_precede + minute + AM_PM);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
```